# Unable to display Lightning:checkboxGroup Correctly in Aura Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm trying to use a `lightning:checkboxGroup` in an aura component to display a group of file names, `contentdocument`, with checkboxes so the user can select the files desired and then perform a delete on these records.

I'm getting a successful call and return of the method results which is a list of strings with the format of `DEBUG|*************************************************** options ({"label": Winnipeg CANADA (1410 Mountain) Lease Extension Agr (revised), "value": 0696w0000000nQ6AAI})` as an example of one file.

The component on the page shows the checkbox, but not the name of the file.

Here is my component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" controller="FilesUtility" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="selectedFiles" type="List" />
    <aura:attribute name="fileList" type="List" />
    
    <lightning:recordEditForm recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                          objectApiName="ContentDocument"
                          onsuccess="{!c.onSuccess}"
                          onerror="{!c.onError}"
                          onsubmit="{!c.onSubmit}"
                          aura:id = "deleteFiles" />
    
    <lightning:messages />
    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" />
    <lightning:checkboxGroup aura:id="checkbox"
                             name="Checkbox Group"
                             label="Delete Files"
                             options="{!v.fileList}"
                             value="{!v.selectedFiles}"/>
</aura:component>
```

JS Controller:

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('******************************* we are inside the doInit function');
    var action = component.get("c.getFilesByAgreement");
    action.setParams({ "id" : component.get("v.recordId") });
    action.setCallback(this, function(result){
        var state = result.getState();
        if(component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS"){
            console.log('************************************** success');
            console.log('************************************** result ' + result.getReturnValue());
            component.set("v.fileList", result.getReturnValue());             
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure that your list is properly "formatted" ?
if you take a look at the collection types, Lists are expected to be returned within square brackets:

`[ 'one', '2', 'three', '{"some" : "thing"}']`

[Collection Types](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_attr_types_collection.htm)

this:

`({"label": Winnipeg CANADA (1410 Mountain) Lease Extension Agr (revised), "value": 0696w0000000nQ6AAI})`

does not seem to be what the list type is expecting to receive.

Comment: Thanks @glls
I updated the format of the JSON string in the apex and then converted the JSON to an object that I can push into a array which I set to my list attribute. It sets properly now.